# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'architect' when start from docker

Tags: python, django, docker

When I trying start Django from docker I get an error

```
server_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
server_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'architect'
openfoundation-container_server_1 exited with code 1
```

But when I run Django manually `"python 3 manage.py runserver 7000"` then the server starts correctly

[image: console output]

my dockerfile

[image]

my docker-compose

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  server:

    build: server/
    command: "python3 ./manage.py runserver"
    ports:
      - 7000:7000

  client:

    build: client/
    command: "npm run dev"
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    depends_on:
      - server
```

tree

[image]

Can u help me please? Thnk!

Comment: You seem to have pasted some images in place of your Dockerfile and your command output.  Can you replace these images with the actual text of these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mount your local directory as a volume in your docker-compose

```
services:
  server:
    volumes:
      - ./server:/server
```

Currently you are not copying or mounting any of your local code in the container